# Access-Control-Allow-Origin and handling from localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, cookies, cors

So, in my React app, I am making some endpoint calls to different servers and I also have withCredentials set to true, since I pass some token/cookie along with all the requests.

Now, how can I make this work on localhost seamlessly? Since I have withCredentials to true, the
Access-Control-Allow-Origin needs to have specific origin and cannot have * (so if host is localhost:3000, it is not allowed and I get CORS error)

Any ideas on making this work both for local testing and for env deployments?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of origins that are allowed to access each environment. Select a means to store this data apropriate for your backend environment.

In your server-side code, read the `Origin` **request** header and compare it to the list of allowed origins for the environment you are running in. If it matches one of them, add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with that value to the response.

---

For example, if you are using Node.js then:

[Using `.env.environmentName` files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) is a common way to provide environment specific data.

[The `cors` middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options) will accept an array of allowed origins for the `origin` configuration option and will compare the `Origin` header to them and generate the right `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.